# GPGME Decrypt showing No Data

Tags: c, encryption, gpgme

I am writing a program where I encrypt a file and send it over an SSL Socket using gpgme. Then, I need to download the file and decrypt it.

My encryption is working fine, but I am having problems with the decryption. My inputBuffer is the contents of the file. When the file is downloaded, the result of the inputBuffer is the first line of the encrypted text. gpgme_strerror(err)) is returning "No Data". It doesn't seem as if the contents of the text is being placed in the cipher text and it doesn't know what to decrypt.

```
{
    bytes = SSL_read(ssl, &inputBuffer, 1024);

    while (bytes > 0)
    {
        err = gpgme_data_new_from_mem(&cipher, inputBuffer, strlen(inputBuffer), 0); 

        err = gpgme_op_decrypt(gctx, cipher, plain);
        fprintf(stderr,"The result from Decrypt: %s\n", gpgme_strerror(err)); // returning no data
        dec_result = gpgme_op_decrypt_result(gctx);
        if (dec_result->unsupported_algorithm)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s:%i: unsupported algorithm: %s\n",
                         __FILE__, __LINE__, dec_result->unsupported_algorithm);
            exit(1);
        }

        fputs(inputBuffer, fp);
        fprintf(stderr, "Number of bytes read %zu\n", bytes);
        fclose(fp);
        fprintf(stderr, "File Uploaded Successfully\n");
        memset(&inputBuffer, '\0', sizeof(inputBuffer));
        bytes = SSL_read(ssl, &inputBuffer, 1024);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    SSL_shutdown(ssl);
}
```

Comment: Did you find an answer to this in the end? I'm having the same issue

Comment: Yes, I was running fclose() too soon, closing my file too early, and the socket was not receiving the full buffer on the other end.